# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; - classcast excpetion in same class but runs fine when called from a different class

Tags: java, generics

```
public class GenericDemo<T> {

    T data[] = (T[])new Object[1];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericDemo<String> gdStr = new GenericDemo<>();
        gdStr.data[0] = new String("Hello"); //Runtime Class cast exception


        GenericData<Integer> dataInt = new GenericData<>();
        dataInt.setObj(new Integer(25));
        System.out.println(dataInt.getObj());

        GenericData<String> dataString = new GenericData<>();
        dataString.setObj("Hello World");
        System.out.println(dataString.getObj());
    }
}

class GenericData<T> {
    private T obj;

    public void setObj(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public T getObj(){
        return obj;
    }
}
```

In the above code runtime error --> gdStr.data[0] = new String("Hello"); but compiles just fine. the same runs fine when value is set and called in getter/setter. May I know the problem here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The cast `(T[])new Object[1]` is theoretically incorrect if `T` is anything other than `Object` -- the object's actual runtime class is `Object[]`, which is not an instance of `String[]`, `Integer[]`, or whatever. It doesn't immediately cause any exceptions because inside an instance of `GenericDemo`, it doesn't know what `T` is, so it can't enforce that `data` is an instance of `T[]` -- it can only enforce that `data` is an instance of the erasure of `T[]`, which is `Object[]`, and that is fine.

So as long as you keep this lie inside of an instance of `GenericDemo`, nothing bad happens. However, if you expose the (incorrect) claim that `data` has type `T[]` to outside the instance, to a place which has a specific idea of what `T` is, then they can have an expectation on the type of `data` that is incorrect. That is what happens here. In the static method `main`, it has a `GenericDemo<String> gdStr`, so it can expect that `gdStr.data` is an instance of `String[]` (and the compiler can insert a cast to it), which it is not. This is why there is an exception.

`GenericData` doesn't have any unsafe casts, so it doesn't have this problem. But let's say you do the same type of unsafe cast, and unsafe holding of an `Object[]` in a `T[]` variable, in a class `GenericData2`, but you do not expose this variable to outside the instance in any way, only dealing with it with the instance's methods, then you will also not get any exception:

```
class GenericData2<T> {
    private T[] data = (T[])new Object[1];

    public void setObj(T obj) {
        this.obj[0] = obj;
    }
    public T getObj(){
        return obj[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: NewAcct !Thank you for the detailed explanation